# How to use updated Twitter API with node.js, "event: field is required"

Tags: node.js, api, npm, twitter

I keep getting the following error when trying to use the Twitter API to send direct messages.

```
message: 'event: field is required',
  code: 214,
  allErrors: [ { code: 214, message: 'event: field is required' } ],
  twitterReply: { errors: [ [Object] ] },
  statusCode: 400 }
{ errors: [ { code: 214, message: 'event: field is required' } ] }
```

Twitter recently updated their api (im told) so to send direct messages the url 'direct_messages/events/new' is now used. I'm using the 'twit' module to access the api.

```
export async function messageTwitter(message, recipient){
    client.post('direct_messages/events/new',{
        screen_name: recipient,
        text: message
    }, (event, error)=>{
            console.log(event)
            console.log(error)
    })
}
```

I want the post request to be properly formatted, i cannot find any info in the documentation that explains how 'event' should be defined.

Comment: Does the Twitter API documentation on Direct Messages not help here? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event

Comment: It does, but I have no idea what it means by the field "event", and i can't find any updated posts to address the updated API.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around based off of the errors I was getting I figured out how to format the object. Sorry I know this was sort of a dumb, poorly asked question. Here is my updated code:

```
export async function messageTwitter(message, recipient){
    client.post('direct_messages/events/new', {
        event: {
            type: "message_create",
            message_create: {
                target: {
                    recipient_id: recipient
                },
                message_data: {
                    text: message
                }
            }
        }
    }, (error, event)=>{
            if(error){
              console.log(error)
            }
            else{
               console.log(event);
             }
    })
}
```